# If else statement isn't outputting responses based on input values

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement, input, output

I want this code to output either Nay or Yay depending on my input value

```
Console.Write("Welcome! Please Select Any Number: ");

int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());

if (x >= 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Yay");
}
else
{
      Console.WriteLine("You are Wrong");
}
```

I initially didn't use the Convert.ToInt32 funtion, but it kept outputting You are wrong, regardless of whether or not the value input went against the initial condition.

At first the Convert.ToInt function was not used and the code kept ouyputting You are wrong, then after using it, it keeps outputting Yay
I want the code to output the word Nay, for whenever my value is is less than 10, yet whatever value I input, the output defaults to Yay
and I want it to output Yay if the values input suit the condition

Comment: I would assume you meant to use `Console.ReadLine()`

Comment: `Console.Read()` reads the next **character** from the input.

Comment: Pressing F1 when your cursor is on built-in classes & methods would launch a relatively comprehensive help page, use them.

Comment: Please put titles in question format, not statements. Also, please us proper grammar to make your post more readable. As is, your post is hard to read and is a big run on sentence. Lastly your question is about basic development that can easily be answered with basic research. Please do some research before posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.Read()` returns an `int` - which is the Unicode value of the next char of the input stream. You want to use `Console.ReadLine()`, which returns the string the user entered (though the user will have to also press the `Enter`/`Return` key on their keyboard).

Also, what if the user enters something that can't be converted to an `int`, like `banana`? You want to use `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32` so that your program wouldn't crash in such a case.

```
Console.Write("Welcome! Please enter any number: ");
var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
if(int.TryParse(userInput, out var x)
{
  if(x >= 10)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Yay");
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("You are Wrong");
  }
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Can't parse {userInput} as an int.");
}
```